# How To Install APC Via Pecl

Tags: php, pecl

- here is the output im getting.

  ```
  showing output  after running this command : pecl install apc
   downloading APC-3.1.13.tgz ...
   Starting to download APC-3.1.13.tgz (171,591 bytes)
     .....................................done: 171,591 bytes
    could not extract the package.xml file from "/build/buildd/php5-5.5.9+dfsg/pear-  build-download/APC-3.1.13.tgz"
    Download of "pecl/apc" succeeded, but it is not a valid package archive
    Error: cannot download "pecl/APC"
    Download failed
    install failed.
  ```

  - I have to  install apc via cmd.
  - problem  im facing is installation failure.

Comment: Which Operating System?

Answer (score 2):

Try using the default system apc install:

```
sudo apt-get install php-apc
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I install PHP APC:

**Download latest stable Version**

PHP APC-3.1.9 (stable) can be found on PECL [page](http://pecl.php.net/package/APC). Download and save (to desktop).

**Begin installation**

Untar APC, move into extracted directory

```
tar xvzf APC-3.1.9.tgz
cd APC-3.1.9/
```

Now, we want to **phpize** current directory. Because I use LAMPP PHP installation, its `phpize` is located in `/opt/lampp/bin`. Then, new `.configure` file will be created (your `php-config` may differ).

```
/opt/lampp/bin/phpize
./configure --with-php-config=/opt/lampp/bin/php-config
```

Then,

```
make
sudo make install
```

**Configure *php.ini* file**

Next, we want to configure APC for use. Edit your *php.ini* file. (mine was located in `/opt/lampp/etc/php.ini`).

```
vim /opt/lampp/etc/php.ini
```

Add these lines (preferably under *Dynamic Extension* section, but you can place it anywhere):

```
extension=apc.so
apc.enabled=1
apc.shm_size=40M
apc.ttl=7200
apc.user_ttl=7200
apc.enable_cli=1
apc.max_file_size=5M
```

also edit `extension_dir` on *php.ini* file

```
extension_dir = "/opt/lampp/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/"
```

your `extension_dir` refers to `make install` result.

Now, look at `phpinfo()` page to verify your APC installation.

References:

[Install guide](http://help.directadmin.com/item.php?id=400)